# Optimal way to change the given array

Tags: javascript

```
var pred = ['z','b','d','e','f','z','g']; //replace 'z' with 'a' & after 'b' add 'c'
var conditions = [
    {new:"a", old:"z", func:"replace"}, //replace z with a
    {new:"c", old:"b", func:'add_and_replace'} // after b add c
]
```

I want to make changes to arr **pred** based on** conditions** The result I'm lookig for is `pred = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','a','g']`
What would be the most optimal way to do it?

Comment: What you have tried so for?

Comment: you should be more clear on what's the full set of operations and how did you decide to encode them so far ... since it seems you already have expectations looking at that conditions array. I mean, replace and add_and_replace are the only operations covered by your logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
let pred = ['z','b','d']; //replace 'z' with 'a' & after 'b' add 'c'

let conditions = [
    {new:"a", old:"z", func:"replace"}, //replace z with a
    {new:"c", old:"b", func:'add_and_replace'} // after b add c
]

function resolveConditions(arr, conditions) {
    for(let condition of conditions) {
        if(condition.func == "replace") {
            arr.splice(arr.indexOf(condition.old), 1, condition.new);
        }
    
        if(condition.func == "add_and_replace") {
            arr.splice(arr.indexOf(condition.old) + 1, 0, condition.new);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

let result = resolveConditions(pred, conditions);
console.log(result);
```

If you need more explainations about the code, you can ask me ;)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The result I'm looking for is ``pred = ['a','b','c','d']``

Comment: I just edited, now it return the expected output ;)

Comment: I've added another question. Could you please have a look at this too? ^_^ https://stackoverflow.com/q/73035185/13701817

Comment: Yes of course, if this answer satisfied you don't forget to `accept the answer` ;)