# What would be the best way to change the array?

Tags: javascript

```
var pred = ['z','b','d','e','z','f','b','d']
                    
var conditions = [
    {new:"a", old:"z", func:"replace"}, //replace z with a
    {new:"c", old:"b", func:'add_and_replace'} // after b add c
]
```

I want to make changes to arr **pred** based on **conditions**

The result I'm looking for is `pred = ['a','b','c','d','e' 'a','f','b','c','d']`

**I'm trying to do it in this way but the output is incorrect**:

```
    var conditions = [
        {new:"a", old:"z", func:"replace"}, //replace z with a
        {new:"c", old:"b", func:'add_and_replace'} // after b add c
    ]
    var pred = ['z','b','d','e','z','f','b','d']
    let new_pred = []
    pred.forEach((pre,i)=>{
        conditions.forEach((con,j)=>{
         
          if(con.func == 'replace' && pre.includes(con.old)){
            new_pred.push(con.new)
          }
          if(con.func == 'add_and_replace' && pre.includes(con.old)){
           new_pred.push(pred[i]);
           new_pred.push(con.new)
         }
        })
        new_pred.push(pred[i])
    })

    pred = new_pred;
    console.log(pred)
```

How could I do it?

Comment: That really depends what you mean by "most optimal"? Do you want easy to read code, the fastest way to do it, the most memory efficient way or what?

Comment: If your code works as it is, then be careful of [premature optimisation](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

Comment: @phuzi But it doesn't work. The result is wrong.

Comment: A case could be made for `switch`, or even using a dispatch object with functions like `{ replace: (new, old, str) => { ... } }` but if it works, it works.

Comment: Please debug your code, add debugging details and ask a specific programming question. [StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) functions.

```js
var conditions = [
    {new:"a", old:"z", func:"replace"}, //replace z with a
    {new:"c", old:"b", func:'add_and_replace'} // after b add c
]
var pred = ['z','b','d','e','z','f','b','d']

for (const condition of conditions) {
    switch (condition.func){
        case "replace":
            pred = pred.map(element => (element === condition.old) ? condition.new : element)
            break
        case "add_and_replace":
            pred = pred.flatMap(element => (element === condition.old) ? [element, condition.new] : element)
            break
    }
}

console.log(pred) // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "f", "b", "c", "d"]
```